# How do I rebuild the catalog on time machine backup hard drive?

Tags: mojave, fsck, fsck-hfs

My Time machine backup drive has started giving me these errors on doing a fsck. How can I rebuild the indexes on this drive? I just upgraded to Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6.

The drive has 2 partitioned as:

```
1.9TB for time machine (HFS+)
100GB for other files (HFS+)
```

Logs:

```
/dev/rdisk2s2: fsck_hfs started at Sat Feb 15 08:37:39 2020
/dev/rdisk2s2: /dev/rdisk2s2: ** /dev/rdisk2s2
/dev/rdisk2s2:    Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.200.4).
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
/dev/rdisk2s2:    The volume name is 2TB
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** Checking extents overflow file.
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** Checking catalog file.
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** Checking multi-linked files.
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** Checking catalog hierarchy.
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** Checking extended attributes file.
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** Checking multi-linked directories.
/dev/rdisk2s2:    Invalid parent for directory inode (id = 11770766)
/dev/rdisk2s2:    (It should be 19 instead of 18)
/dev/rdisk2s2:    Invalid name for directory inode (id = 11770766)
/dev/rdisk2s2:    (It should be dir_11770766 instead of temp11770766)
/dev/rdisk2s2:    Incorrect number of directory hard links
/dev/rdisk2s2: ** The volume 2TB could not be verified completely.
/dev/rdisk2s2: fsck_hfs completed at Sat Feb 15 09:02:06 2020
```

On a ubuntu VM, I am seeing:

$ sudo fsck.hfsplus -dfy /dev/sda2

```
** /dev/sda2
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=1024 cacheSize=32768K.
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking multi-linked files.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Volume check failed.
volume check failed with error 5 
    volume type is pure HFS+ 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 2 0x02 
    alternate VHB is at block 3711042830 0xdd32050e 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x07 
    total sectors for volume = 3711042832 0xdd320510 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
```

I tried to rebuild the catalog using the -r option (on ubuntu) but that failed:

$ sudo fsck.hfsplus -dfyr /dev/sda2

```
** /dev/sda2
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=1024 cacheSize=32768K.
    could not get volume block 2, err 5 

    could not get alternate volume header at 3711042830, err 5 
    unknown volume type 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x01 
    total sectors for volume = 3711042832 0xdd320510 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
```

Comment: Have you tried using diskutil?